# Parameters of a Class Type: Java

Tags: java, methods

Can someone explain to me in detail the solution to this answer? I am not 100% sure **how** Java ensures that this will not be done.

Q. What is the biggest difference between a parameter of a primitive type and a parameter of a class type?

The biggest difference is in how a method handles arguments that correspond to the different kinds of parameters. A method cannot change the value of a variable of a primitive type that is an argument to the method, nor can it replace an argument of a class type with another object. On the other hand, a method can change the values of an object of a class type whose name is an argument to the method.

Comment: The various answers in the linked post explain in detail how both primitive types and reference types are handled as arguments to method invocations.

Comment: Ignore the title of the question. The answers themselves address what you are asking about.